# How to change select value on hascchange

Tags: jquery, ajax, hashchange

Im using Ben Allman's BBQ plugin to handle hash changes. Ive had no issues when links or tabs trigger the hash change, but need some help with the same functionality when applied to a `<select>`.

I can get the hash to change and the remote content to load on select change, but I would like the select to match the option to the hash in the url.

So when you select'Car' the page will load the appropriate remote content, the has will change to 'foo.com/#!Page_Car.php' and the select would show 'Car'. This all works fine, but I would like the same when you use the browser back button to trigger the url change, everything works except changing the select list's selected value.

**update - solved the problem**

```
<select name="HashSelect" id="HashSelect" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="#!Page_Car.php">Car</option>
    <option value="#!Page_Plane.php">Plane</option>
    <option value="#!Page_Boat.php">Boat</option>      
</select>
```

and the js

```
$(function(){
    $.param.fragment.ajaxCrawlable( true );
    var cache = {
        '': $('.contentDefault')
    };
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
        var url = $.param.fragment();
        $( '#content-target' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();
        url && $( 'a[href="#!' + url + '"]' );
        if ( cache[ url ] ) {
            cache[ url ].show();
            $('#HashSelect option').filter(function() {
                return this.value && this.value == location.hash;
            }).prop('selected', true);
        } else {
            $( '#content-loading' ).show();
            cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="content-item"/>' )
            .appendTo( '#content-target' )
            .load( url, function(){
                $( '#content-loading' ).hide();
                //This worked for me
                $('#HashSelect option').filter(function() {
                    return this.value && this.value == location.hash;
                }).prop('selected', true);
            });
            $( '#content-loading' ).hide();
        }
    });
    $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
});
```

Comment: so you solved your problem by introducing `onchange` attribute on `<select>`?